# Usable time & date format in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, csv, python-3.6

I might be a noob asking this question as I don't find the answer for this problem. I have "170101,,,,,,00:00"  as date in YYmmDD format in a csv file. Piece of code:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

with open('T2_x.csv') as readcsvfile:
    readcsv=csv.reader(readcsvfile)
    header=next(readcsv)

    data=[]
    for row in readcsv:
        date=datetime.strptime(row[0],"%Y%m%d")
        time=datetime.strptime(row[6],"%H:%M")
        data.append(time,date)
        print(data)

with open('T2_xw.csv','w',newline='')as writecsvfile:
    writecsv=csv.writer(writecsvfile)
    writecsv.writerows([data])
```

The time format works fine ("%H:%M"). But providing "%Y%m%d" as the format yields `"ValueError: time data '170101' does not match format '%Y%m%d'".`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

> %y Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.  00, 01, ...,
>   99

You must change:

```
date=datetime.strptime(row[0],"%Y%m%d")
```

to:

```
date=datetime.strptime(row[0],"%y%m%d")
```